# linking the cms page to particular image

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I have created a CMS page with the name collection.html and added the code like

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

I want to link this CMS page to the image which is displaying in the other page. How to link this page to particular image in the other page?

Comment: Why do you want to link to an image on another page?

Answer (score 1):

- If the image is in CMS page or Static Block then you can do by this way

  ```
  <a href=" {{store direct_url="identifier_of_cms_page"}} ">
      <img ... />
  </a>
  ```
- If the image is in phtml page then

  ```
  <a href=" <?php echo $this->getUrl('identifier_of_cms_page');?> ">
      <img .. />
  </a>
  ```

Comment: Check in chrome in the html of what url is of that image, and then hard link to it, if you only want to link to a single image, and display that in a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

While you have created a `CMS Page`, you would have added some `URL Key` for the page.

- Getting the `URL` in `phtml`

  > $this->getUrl('cms-page-url-key');
- Getting the `URL` in `CMS Page` or `Static Block`

  > {{store direct_url="cms-page-url-key"}}

Answer (score 0):

To get the CMS page url in template file

```
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct' => 'cms-page-key'));
```

To pass parameter with this

```
$this->getUrl('', array('_direct' => 'cms-page-key', '_query' =>'a=5&b=6'));
```